How to Clean (Denoise) an Image using opencv?
I am trying to detect only the bigger letters and trying to save them in a plane(imagine it as a black board and i am trying to print the bigger letter in it).

Steps i did so far

converted the image to hsv.

using inRange functionality i created a mask.

added a morphological close so that i remove smaller noise.

finally started plotting the big letters for my reference(few letters are not detected as explained below).

when i print the black board one or 2 letters gets omitted.


I have the code below
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Load the image
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/run/media/cams/B4267D4B267D0F9A/Downloads/2.png");
//    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/run/media/cams/B4267D4B267D0F9A/Downloads/np7.jpg");
//    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/run/media/cams/B4267D4B267D0F9A/Downloads/license-plate.png");

    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to load image." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat resizedImage;
    cv::Size newSize(513, 134);

    cv::resize(image,resizedImage,newSize);

    int rows = resizedImage.rows;
    int cols  = resizedImage.cols;

    cv::Mat result(rows, cols ,resizedImage.type(), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    // Convert to grayscale
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(resizedImage, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    imshow("Gray-img", gray);

    // Convert to hsv
    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::cvtColor(resizedImage, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    imshow("HSV", hsv);

    cv:: Mat others;
    cv::cvtColor(resizedImage, others, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL);
    imshow("HSV_FULL", others);


    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Scalar lower(0, 0, 0);          // Lower bound
    cv::Scalar upper(179, 100, 130);    // Upper bound

    cv::inRange (others, lower, upper, mask);
    imshow("Mask", mask);

    // Create a rectangular structuring element
    cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));

    // Perform morphological closing
    cv::Mat close;
    cv::morphologyEx(mask, close, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 1);

    // Merge the single-channel closed image into a 3-channel image
    cv::Mat extract;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3, close); // Create a vector with three copies of 'close'
    cv::merge(channels, extract); // Merge them into a single 3-channel image

    cv::imshow("Closed Mask", close);
//    cv::imshow("Merged Image", extract);

    // Find contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
//    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(close, contours, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (const auto& c : contours) {
            // Get bounding rectangle
            cv::Rect boundingBox = cv::boundingRect(c);
            int area = boundingBox.width * boundingBox.height;

            // Filter based on area
            if ( area>2500 && area<5000) {
                // Draw rectangle on the original image
                cv::rectangle(resizedImage, boundingBox, cv::Scalar(36, 255, 12), 3);

                // Extract region from 'extract' and copy it to 'result'
                cv::imshow("contourssss", resizedImage);
                waitKey(0);

                // Extract region from 'extract' and copy it to 'result'
                cv::Mat roi = extract(boundingBox); // Region of Interest from extract
                roi.copyTo(result(boundingBox)); // Copy to the corresponding area in result
            }
        }

    // Display the result
    cv::imshow("Contours", result);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;

}


try to increase the size of your closing kernel   "cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));"

as a starting point for playing around with images, might I suggest trying a guassian or sobel filter.
cv2 has tutorials on both. I think guassian blurring may get you where you want to go.
https://www.opencv-srf.com/2018/03/gaussian-blur.html
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html
you may also want to play around with some DFT or laplacian techniques. These are more traditional methods used for "edge detection" and generic denoising.
optical character recognition (OCR), is a well established field and there are a lot of resources out there for it. Here is a good tutorial I found: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/10/20/using-machine-learning-to-denoise-images-for-better-ocr-accuracy/
